# Map<String, Object> from List<Object> with setting attribute of object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Item> ItemList` and `List<String> selectedItemList`

`Item : {id:String, name:string, isSelected:Boolean}`

I want to transform  ItemList to a `Map<String,Item>` where `isSelected` = true or false (condition: `selectedItemList.contains(ItemList[n])`).
key is the id of Item.

I try this:

```
Map<String, Item> result = itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, value -> itemSelectedList.contains(value.getName())));
```

What I expect :

```
0 : {0,"item1", true}, 1 : {1,"item1", true} , 2 : {2,"item1", false}...
```

Comment: What was the problem with what you tried?

Comment: the logic is wrong. I dont know how to get the value I want ( I don't know how to use condition in stream, toMap...)

Comment: A `Map` associates a key with a value, in your case, you declared the key to be a `String` and the value to be `Item`. Whatever kind of data structure your `0 : {0,"item1", true}, 1 : {1,"item1", true} , 2 : {2,"item1", false}` is supposed to represent, it is not a `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

Your value here is a boolean, not an Item.
You should filter your list first, then create your Map, like this :

```
Map<String, Item> result = itemList.stream()
    .filter(item -> itemSelectedList.contains(item.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, value -> value));
```

EDIT : given your edit, you don't want to filter but valorize the isSelected property, you can just use a constructor then :

```
Map<String, Campaign> result = itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, value -> new Item(value.getId(), value.getName(), itemSelectedList.contains(value.getName())));
```

Comment: But with this solution I lose not selected items. I wanna keep all items (selected or not) , I must change only change the attribute "isSelected".